# Factory method or constructor fragment creation

Tags: android, oop, android-fragments, kotlin, factory

Here we have a little debate about creating a fragment.

There is a way to create a fragment using the factory method and the usual constructor call.  The essence of the dispute is that the factory method for creating a fragment uses a static method and memory is allocated for each static method.

If our application consists of dozens or more fragments, will the factory method affect performance?

Comment: have you tried benchmarking to see whether "having more static methods" is actually a problem?

Comment: Now we have an application in development, there are no problems, but this is for the future when the application will be large

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance impact, but to me, if you need fragment arguments it sounds like you don't really have much choice. If Android decides to recreate your Fragment later, it's going to call the no-argument constructor of your fragment. This is usually the reason why we prefer the factory approach and also why we use the fragment arguments bundle - so they're available on recreating. That said, I don't know if this is still an issue if you never want to instantiate fragments and pass arguments.

Comment: We can overloading constructor with params and store into bundle